# What sort of applications does the normal distribution have in electrical engineering?

Tags: theory

Need to know just two. Sorry for posting this here (arduino). Seems there isn't a soft-questions tag. Thank you for your help.

Comment: answered in http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/263629/what-sort-of-applications-does-the-normal-distribution-have-in-the-field-of-elec/263632#263632

Comment: cross posting is a bad habit on SE. Questions will be migrated by mods whenever necessary.

Comment: It got closed on math. I think we can do a better job answering here. Lets keep out open.

Comment: keep <strike>out</strike> it open.

Answer (score 6):

I'll give one example:

Here's a plot from the datasheet of [Analog Devices AD8659](http://www.analog.com/en/all-operational-amplifiers-op-amps/operational-amplifiers-op-amps/ad8659/products/product.html) precision operational amplifier (or *op-amp*). This shows the distribution of a parameter called input offset voltage over a sample of a few hundred individual amplifiers.

[image]

In a working circuit, the offset voltage typically contributes an error to a measurement when the op-amp is being used for signal conditioning, or in a feedback variable when the op-amp is being used in a control loop.

When you're designing a circuit with this op-amp, you might model this distribution fairly accurately with a normal distribution, and do a *Monte Carlo* analysis to find out how the performance of your whole circuit is likely to be distributed in response to this variation in the op-amp performance as well as other variables in other components in the circuit.

Answer (score 2):

I'll add to what the previous answer says.  It is very important, with the additional concept of the variance and/or standard deviation.  The standard deviation is expressed as sigma and the sigma levels are important to predict various performance levels, how well a design circuit will meet specifications and failure rates.  Various sigma levels are used at different parts of the design process and is embodied in what is known as the six sigma process used in quality control.

On EDit, noise processes are described by probability density functions some of which are normally distributed.  So if you deal with noise and fundamental limits in design, you'll also need to understand this.  In this case there is also the poisson distribution.

Comment: Your edit should eventually generate another whole answer (from you, me, or somebody)...